# Java regex add space everytime number found in the string

Tags: java, regex

For example I have the string `number1number1number1`. Then I want to change it to `number 1 number 1 number 1`. 
So, for every single number that I find and not separated by a space, I will add a space. What should I do?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: What should happen to `number12number`? Should it become `number 1  2 number` (there are two spaces between 1 and 2), or `number 12 number`?

Comment: Also what about numbers at start and end of text? Should they also be surrounded by space from *both* sides?

Comment: `number12number` should be `number 12 number`

Comment: What about `1number2number3`? Should it become `_1_number_2_number_3_` (`_` represents spaces) or `1 number 2 number 3`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe,

```
(?<=[0-9])(?=[a-z])|(?<=[a-z])(?=[0-9])
```

might simply work OK.

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/YR604J/1/)

#### Test

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;


public class RegularExpression{

    public static void main(String[] args){

        final String regex = "(?<=[0-9])(?=[a-z])|(?<=[a-z])(?=[0-9])";
        final String string = "number1number1number1";
        final String subst = " ";

        final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
        final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);

        final String result = matcher.replaceAll(subst);

        System.out.println(result);

    }
}
```

#### Output

```
number 1 number 1 number 1
```

---

If you wish to simplify/modify/explore the expression, it's been explained on the top right panel of [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/YR604J/1/). If you'd like, you can also watch in [this link](https://regex101.com/r/YR604J/1/debugger), how it would match against some sample inputs.

---

Answer (score 1):

Split the string using the numbers as delimeters keeping those delimeters and join back using string join by adding a space as delimeter

```
    String str ="1number123number1number1";
    String regex = "((?<=\\d+)(?!\\d)|(?<!\\d)(?=\\d+))";
    String replaced = String.join(" ", str.split(regex));
    System.out.println(replaced);
```